# Standardizing data for neural network: High density at mean, large amount of outlier values

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, normalization, standardization

I have not been able to find much information on good practices for dealing with these two issues. The first is a high concentration around the mean, and the second is a large amount of values far away from the mean.

First the input distribution shows a large number of values at zero. To normalize I simply computed the mean/std without the zeros included which I'm not sure is a good approach. I am running a convolutional neural net, so I don't think masking out the values is an option
[image]

These are the values of the output distribution with the extreme concentration at and around zero (top values are clipped).

[image]

Comment: What are the meaning of zeros? Are these pixel values?

Comment: NNs do not have assumptions over the data distribution

Comment: The zeros are pixel values yes. Not working with rgb data